# CXF Client Interceptor to always call another method first?

Tags: java, authentication, cxf, webservice-client

I'm dealing with a web service that needs to have an "authentication" method called and the returned token placed in a special header in order to do the next operation, every time. It seems logical to try to do this in a CXF interceptor. I would see it working as

CXF client object injected into business logic object. BusinessLogic Object calls Operation A. Interceptor determines Operation B needs to be called first and calls Op B, then adds the header to the original call A and then it is outgoing.

Obviously this would make sense to do it atomically or potentially recursively (if the Interceptor knows that calls to Op B pass on through). An ugly, hackish way I would like to avoid would be to have the Interceptor have a cyclic dependency on the service. I would also like to avoid the ugly hackish way of essentially standing up two client objs and having one intercepted and the other not. It seems like there should be some way to do this, and indeed I know of the Service class having a method dispatcher, but I don't know how to invoke an operation that will result in an outgoing call.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a really old question and @jcalvert has long since arrived at a solution or another career.

On first blush, I question the wisdom of performing I/O in an Interceptor chain, wherein propagating meaningful information upon failure might be a challenge, never mind the inefficiency of having to re-authenticate on every operation.

And yes, it is possible to create a state-full interceptor which would maintain what is effectively a session token, but the client would be obliged to have a "log-out" operation to dispose of the association.

My first suggestion would be to deal with situation at the application layer: alter the client's interface such that every operation requires an authorization token. If not present, the web service obtains one and returns it on all operations.